Dynamic SQL to convert many columns to rows
I have a table that contains over 100 columns and I would like to keep 2 columns as fixed columns and transform the rest. I can do this with union but it will be a lots of work and long code. I would like a shorter SQL code to achieve same result.
SELECT 
material, plant, 'name' AS column_name, name AS column_value FROM materialtable 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
material, plant, 'category' AS column_name, category AS column_value FROM materialtable 
UNION ALL 
SELECT material, plant, 'rating' AS column_name, CAST(rating AS STRING) AS column_value FROM materialtable UNION ALL 
SELECT 
material, plant, 'price' AS column_name, CAST(price AS STRING) AS column_value FROM materialtable

thanks
I have tried below code but having syntax error "Syntax error: Unclosed string literal at".
I am working on Big query platform.
DECLARE query STRING;

SET query = (
  SELECT CONCAT(
    'SELECT * FROM (',
    STRING_AGG(
      FORMAT(
        'SELECT 
           material,
           plant,
           "%s" AS column_name,
           CAST(%s AS STRING) AS column_value
         FROM materialtable',
        column_name,
        column_name
      ),
      ' UNION ALL '
    ),
    ')'
  )
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'materialtable'
    AND column_name NOT IN ('material', 'plant')
  ORDER BY ordinal_position
)

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;
                              


In BigQuery, DECLARE and SET cannot be used to build the query directly in the way you’re attempting due to BigQuery's SQL syntax. Instead, you can use a subquery or EXECUTE IMMEDIATE directly with a nested SELECT to build and run your query in one go.

Please check the unpivot syntax https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unpivot_operator. You need a list of all the columns to convert. This is the fasted route: From the BigQuery schema page of the table please copy the information of all columns as a table and past this meta data to Google sheets or Excel. For the unviot  statement you have to still cast integers to string, but this is one line of code per column. This can be done in gone in Google Sheets or Excel.

This is happening because of newline between the static columns list:
Try this way:

BEGIN


DECLARE query STRING;
SET query = (
  SELECT CONCAT(
    'SELECT * FROM (',
    STRING_AGG(      FORMAT( 'SELECT    material,  plant, "%s" AS column_name, CAST(%s AS STRING) AS column_value   FROM materialtable',
        column_name,        column_name      ),      ' UNION ALL '    ),    ')'  )  FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'materialtable'AND column_name NOT IN ('material', 'plant')
  
);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;  

END;

